# how to insert tab on a text file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to insert a tab as a delimiter. I can not get it working the way I want to.
this is the out put:

[image]

and this is the text data

```
name surname    job 00300   here
name    teacher 065 test
```

I have tried different variations of echoing but i am very new to bash so it did not work

```
echo -e "\t$nameUser\t$jobUser\t$phoneUser\t$locationUser" >>$HOME/$DATAFILENAME    ### add
```

and this is how i display

```
grep -n -i "." $HOME/$DATAFILENAME | sort -k 2 -t $'\t' ###
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe your output to `column`:

```
{ echo -e "ID\tName\tJob\tPhone\tLocation" && grep -n -i "." $HOME/$DATAFILENAME | sort -k 2 -t $'\t';} | column -ts$'\t'
```

Comment: what about the header of the columns? How can i align them with the data?

Comment: They will be aligned too if they also have tab as field separator.

Comment: I have just echoed them before displaying the records. echo -e "ID\tName\tJob\tPhone\tLocation"

Comment: You can do: `echo -e "ID\tName\tJob\tPhone\tLocation" && grep -n -i "." $HOME/$DATAFILENAME | sort -k 2 -t $'\t' | column -ts$'\t'`

Comment: Oh sorry, try this: `{ echo -e "ID\tName\tJob\tPhone\tLocation" && grep -n -i "." $HOME/$DATAFILENAME | sort -k 2 -t $'\t';} | column -ts$'\t'`

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf`:

```
printf '\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$nameUser" "$jobUser" "$phoneUser" "$locationUser" >> "$HOME/$DATAFILENAME"
```